# Bar on side of plot that shows second group/category

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a plot that visualizes data as I intended with this code:

```
library(ggplot2)

data = data.frame()

for (x in seq(1,10)){
data = rbind(data, data.frame(x = rnorm(10, sd=0.1) + x, y = seq(10,1), group = x,
                              category = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 3), "d")))
}

data$group = as.factor(data$group)

ggplot() +
  theme(legend.position="none", panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank()) +
  geom_path(data = data, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y, col= group, alpha=0.5)) +
  geom_point(data = data, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y, col= group))
```

[image]

I now want to add a bar at the side that explains the grouping defined in the category column. A legend or labels of this category should also be shown.
[image]

Comment: How are colors and height mapped to categories in the bar?

Comment: The colors of the bar should be different from the plot (the similarity is by accident). The exact height is not important, as long as you can see the mapping of the "rows" to the bar

Comment: @Benni Have you seen my answer? Does it help?

Answer (score 2):

First generate a category vector

```
# list the categories by their freqencies
cgy <- as.data.frame(table(data$category), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# convert the values so that a "0" category finds place
# the "0" category is needed because groups starting at "1"
cgy$Freq <- cgy$Freq/10*9
cgy <- rbind(c(0, 10), cgy)  # bind a "0" category 
# get the desired vector
cgy.v <- unlist(sapply(1:nrow(cgy), function(x) rep(cgy[x, 1], cgy[x, 2])))
rm(cgy)  # clean up
```

***Your plot***

```
p <- ggplot() +
  theme(legend.position="none", 
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank()) +
  geom_path(data=data, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, col= group, alpha=0.5)) +
  geom_point(data=data, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y, col= group))
```

***Add***

```
p + geom_bar(data=data, aes(0, y = as.integer(category)/22),
             fill = factor(sort(cgy.v), 
                           labels=(c("white", "blue", "orange", "yellow", "green"))),
             stat = "identity") +
# the labels: 
geom_text(aes(x=0, 
              y=c(as.integer(table(cgy.v)))/10, 
              label=c("",sort(unique(cgy.v))[-1])), 
          size=4, 
          color="black", position=position_stack(vjust=.5))
```

***Yielding***

[image]

Comment: The scale is a bit problematic. How can this approach be modified to autoscale the bars depending on the number of rows? The bar should also start and stop with the rows. And is there also the possibility to add a label or legend to the bars?

Comment: You were right, didn't look pretty. I found this tricky, but I can provide a "hack". Also there are labels now. See my edited answer. What do you think, might this help you?